# How to print EAN-13 barcodes in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to add a barcode to my report template, its' an EAN13 barcode here's the code  :

```
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement uuid="af782895-f1d3-4e1d-b200-1f2ecf18b4fa" x="67" y="17" width="478" height="81"/>
            <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="EAN13" drawText="true" checksumRequired="false" barWidth="3" barHeight="10">
                <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[142155363254]]></jr:codeExpression>
            </jr:barbecue>
        </componentElement>
```

When i generate the report i on ly get the code expression , no barcode drawed 
Here's the template design :

[image]

I think that the EAN13 is not installed with IReport. 
So How can i add it to IReport?.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to use the Barcode4J library instead of the Barbecue library to print the barcode.

Answer (score 0):

barHeight is too low, try something like 50 or don't specify any bar height.